# How do I insert data while updating?

Tags: php, mysql

There are two tables called table1 and table2

both table has got same index. when updating table1 and table2 if table2 hasnt got a data and table1 has got the same then it should insert that data to table2. so that both tables got the data and is updated. how can I do this??

Answer (score 0):

create a trigger on table 1 to query for the new row in table 2.  if not found, insert.

Answer (score 0):

showing code would help, but one option is to use [REPLACE()](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replace.html) it will add if needed to replace otherwise, if you really need two identical tables you should look in to [replication](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/replication.html) and [stored procedures](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/stored-programs-views.html)